# How to solve $A\tan\theta-B\sin\theta=1$

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering if it is possible to solve
$$A\tan\theta-B\sin\theta=1$$
for $\theta$, where $A>0,B>0$ are real constants.

For sure this can be straightforwardly implemented numerically, but maybe an alternative exists :)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it graphical as well:

You can fiddle [here](http://ggbtu.be/m3185997).

[image: graphical solution]

If you ignore $2\pi$-periodicity you seem to end up with between two and four solutions.

Comment: The OP stated that B is positive, and there is a negative in front, so your plot is incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

$$\tan x=\frac{2\tan \frac x2}{1-\tan^2 \frac x2}=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}$$
$$\sin x=\frac{2\tan \frac x2}{1+\tan^2 \frac x2}=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

Comment: This yields a quartic equation :(

Comment: what's bad about that? There is definitely a finite radical form solution to every real valued quartic that could ever come from this equation.

Comment: The manual calculation of a quartic equation is possible but in general laboursome and errorprone. You end up with long formulas.

Comment: @JackLam Sure there is, but people seem to prefer to solve such equations numerically. I would too.

Comment: @JackLam: in practice quartic equations are often bad news. The formulas are heavy, you need to switch to complex numbers, discussion of the number of roots is tedious...

Comment: It seems that most people don't like tha analytical solution of quartics. If I may, I join the club.

Comment: This is reciprocal of the standard substitution $x = 2 \arctan(t)$ $$\begin{aligned} \cos x & \rightarrow \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \\ \sin x & \rightarrow \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \end{aligned}$$. But, if it works, it works!

Answer (score 2):

Like any other quartic equation, there is a classical way to solve it explicitly in terms of radicals; but this is generally very messy. It is practically much easier, and no less accurate in the final analysis, to solve it by a numerical method such as Newton--Raphson.